# GAS web app form to spreadsheet not update itself

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, bootstrap-4, web-applications

I have built a web app with GAS that send the data on submit to a google spreadsheet.

Sometimes it happens that if I don't update the google spreadsheet manually, the data just entered in the form doesn't appear in the spreadsheet.

Why? Something is missing in the code I need to add?

**This is my code.gs:**

```
function doGet(request) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index')
      .evaluate();
}

/* @Include JavaScript and CSS Files */
function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}

/* @Process Form */
function processForm(formObject) {
  var url = "xxx";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  
  ws.appendRow([formObject.azienda,
                formObject.test,
                formObject.field1,
                formObject.field2,
                formObject.field3]);
}

function sceltaatecoedatiseguenti() {
  var sheet   =  SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxx").getSheetByName("Sheet3");
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var myRange = sheet.getRange("A2:D" + lastRow);  // Modified
  var data    = myRange.getValues();
  var optionsHTML = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i+=1) {
    optionsHTML += `<option data-values="${data[i][1]};${data[i][2]};${data[i][3]}">${data[i][0]}</option>`;  // Modified
  };
  return optionsHTML;
}
```

**This is my javascript.html:**

```
<script>
  // Prevent forms from submitting.
  function preventFormSubmit() {
    var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
    for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
      forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      });
    }
  }
  window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit);    
      
      
  function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
    google.script.run.processForm(formObject);
    document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
  }
  
  // Funzione scelta ateco e dati seguenti -prima parte-
  function setValues(select) {
  const [v1, v2, v3] = select.options[select.selectedIndex].dataset.values.split(";");
  document.getElementById("field1").value = v1;
  document.getElementById("field2").value = v2;
  document.getElementById("field3").value = v3;
}

  // Funzione scelta ateco e dati seguenti -seconda parte-
  const select = document.getElementById("test");
  setValues(select);
  select.addEventListener("change", () => setValues(select));
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <base target="_top">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
                        <h1>Master Leads</h1>

                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                <label for="azienda">Azienda</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="azienda" name="azienda" required="">
                            </div>
                            
                        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                            <span class="badge badge-primary">Codici Ateco</span>
                        </div>
                            
                        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                             <label for="test">Ateco 1</label>
                             <select class="custom-select" name="test" id="test">
                             <?!= sceltaatecoedatiseguenti(); ?>
                             </select>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="form-group col-md-10">
                            <label for="field1">Sottocategoria</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="field1" name="field1" readonly>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                            <label for="field2">Divisione</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="field2" name="field2" readonly>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label for="field3">Sezione</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="field3" name="field3" readonly>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Inserisci in Master Leads</button>
                    </form>
                    <div id="output"></div>
                </div>
            </div>      
        </div>
    </body>
    <?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>
</html>
```

Comment: By "update the spreadsheet manually" do you mean hitting the refresh button?

Comment: @ziganotschka Yes, correct. Or after I add some new rows.

Comment: And if you don't hit the refresh button - do you see the from submission after waiting some minutes or not at all? It's normal that sometimes there is some delay.

Comment: Probably the form submit the data, but only when I add some rows or hit the refresh button, the data are visible.

Comment: Any solution for this issue?

Comment: As mentioned before - some delay in the automatic refreshment is normal, also, if you had the spreadsheet open for a long time - close and reopen might help. If you want me to have a look either your specific WebApp causes problems - please provide full working code including the HTML part for reproducing purposes.

Comment: @ziganotschka I have added the HTML in the question.

Comment: I just ran your code with no issues. Can you see any error in the [browser console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console#:~:text=The%20Browser%20Console%20is%20like,than%20a%20single%20content%20tab.&text=But%20while%20the%20Web%20Console,of%20the%20browser's%20chrome%20window.) at form submission? Try with a new spreadsheet. Make sure that it has at least two rows with data in sheet `Data`.

Comment: I have no error. The problem is only the sheet. It needs to be update sometimes manually to show the new entries. How can I have always the last row empty after new submission?

Comment: You mean inserting an additional empty row after submission? e.g. an empty string?

Comment: I saw that when in the sheet there is the last row empty, a new submission works. So it could be a solution to have always an empty row at the end of the sheet.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot reproduce your issue since for me the form data directly appears in the sheet without refreshing. Do you have some `importrange` or other formula in the sheet? CAn you provide a sample spreadsheet that gives you this problem?

Comment: No. It is a simple sheet without any formula. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1V1qobGGWc4Ww2ttC9EMJbSvOVFoUbZBU3OB5qNg5VoY/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

**Conclusions after testing with your spreadsheet:**

1. I could reproduce the issue with your spreadsheet
2. I could reproduce the issue when making a copy of your spreadsheet
3. The issue does not occur when creating a brand new spreadsheet

Thus, the issue must be related to some setting in your spreadsheet.

You can either create a new spreadsheet from scratch or use the following workaround:

**Go to `File - > Spreadsheet Settings` and change `Calculation` to `On change and every minute`.**

This seems to solve your problem.

[image]

Comment: I performed this change already in your original sreadsheet at it works for me since then. Can you confirm?

Comment: You are using a different spreadsheet now. Can you confirm that it works for your on the one where I modified the settings: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1V1qobGGWc4Ww2ttC9EMJbSvOVFoUbZBU3OB5qNg5VoY/edit#gid=0

Comment: I do not see you having the spreadsheet open or having submitted any data to it recently.

Comment: Look now. There would be in the row 24 the entry "testlast". Update the sheet